# How to track if a user is logged in by session?

Tags: java, session, authentication

I am trying to come up with a mechanism to check if a user has logged in, because certain pages on my web services are available only to registered users. I have my thoughts formalized in the following pseudocode.

```
void login(username, password)
{
      if (username == db.user.username && password == db.user.password)
          username.session = startSession(username);
      else
            response.redirect("/login");
}

String startSession(String username)
{
     String sessionID = encoder.encode(randomBytes, username);  /* generates
a random session id*/
     mysql.session_table.insert(username, sessionID);  /* save the session 
id to session table */

     return sessionID;
}

String getSession(String username)
{
     return username.session;
}


boolean isSessionNew(sessionID)
{
     if (sessionID.age > threshold)
           return false;
     else
           return true;
}
```

Basically, when a user successfully logs in, I will generate a random session ID (startSession method) and save the sessionID, the username, along with the timestamp of its creation to the mysql database table "session". When the user visits a protected web page, the page will check if the user has a valid session ID (by session's age).

My concern about this design is it may incur too much overhead in communicating with the database. Is there an easier and secure way to track user login session?

Answer (score 1):

Session tracking is a pretty common task...  You have an HttpSession object ([javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)) where you can store attributes.  You can also find out about all valid sessions with the HttpSessionContext object.

here's a quick tut:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-session-tracking.htm